# Wordpress shortcode, backslash added in front of double quotation marks

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, magic-quotes

I need to add some html to shortcode image tag for example

```
<img src="http://image.com/design/images/5Stars.png" alt="5 star rating">
```

When I check value in database, I can see all double quotation marks formatted with backslashes

```
<img src=\"http://image.com/design/Images/5Stars.png\" alt=\"5 star rating\">
```

I have tried to use “htmlspecialchars()” and “esc_attr()” but when I using shortcode I can see simple text instead of html.

Comment: you can use `stripslashes()` while saving in database.

Comment: no, stripslashes() give same result

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ob_start` like this example:

```
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
      return ob_get_clean(); }
```